# Does MsBuild wait until another MsBuild process finished that is started by different thread , if there are a dependencies between them?

Tags: c#, multithreading, process, msbuild, parallel.foreach

I have method  that starts a MSBuild to build distinct projects like this.

```
var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
                FileName = msBuildPath,
                Arguments = string.Format(ConfigurationHelper.BuildArguments, buildPath, outputPath, logFilePath)
            };

var process = new Process { StartInfo = startInfo };
var result = process.Start();
process.WaitForExit();  //wait for the process to get build results
```

Another method calls it for every projects that are in a list with using **Parallel.Foreach** (May be it is not good way). It becomes more faster than using one thread but I want to know that whether the projects are built **successfully**, if there are dependencies among projects and their process are started at the same time.

Comment: How would one thread of one msbuild know about what you want to achieve in another thread of msbuild dependencies or not? if the projects arent relying on the outputs of other ms builds then this would probably be ok as they "probably" only need read access to your source. Do you have a specific problem, or is this hypothetical ?

Comment: Yes, you are right but I am little confused. MSBuild builds specified project using the csproj file, it checks the dependencies and required assemblies  so does it wait ? if the depended assembly is building.